# Is it possible to intercept websocket traffic in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Can I capture WebSocket data that is sent while I'm running my selenium tests? I tried using [this](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire) library but had no luck. I'm also using python 3.x and the chromedriver as a reference.